# How to find a directive within a controller and update it's data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*I'm very new to AngularJS and probably because of that I couldn't google the answer to my question but I really want to refactor my app in an MVC way until it will totally become a big piece of spaghetti :)*

I have a directive that should indicate the number of users in groups that are logged in right now. Say it looks like this:

```
angular.module('dashboard').directive('indicator',
    function($scope) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { free: '=' },
            template: '<div><h3>Free<h3><span>{{free}}</span></div>'
        };
        return directive;
    });
```

This number updates instantly when it is changed for some group (I'm using SignalR for that). The JSON I'm getting from the server when something changes looks like this

```
{ 
  groupId: 123,
  loggedIn: 12,
  onPause: 2,
  total: 20
}
```

So I need somehow (as I think) to find the directive that is displaying data for a group with the given ID, and update it's scope object. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: If wired correctly then there is no need to *find a directive* and update it's data. Though without your html and maybe a usable [example](http://plnkr.co/) it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<indicator free="freeVal"></indicator>
```

in your view with

```
$scope.freeVal = 25;
```

in your controller will show you Free25

Every time you change $scope.freeVal - shown value will also change.

So you don't need to change scope value from directive - just pass scope value to your directive (free="freeVal") and change value in scope when new data arrives - value in directive and in view will change automatically.